# TeamCity triggers too many builds for a new branch

Tags: git, build, continuous-integration, teamcity, feature-branch

When I create a new branch `B` from branch `A` and do a single commit, TeamCity triggers multiple builds on `B`, although I would expect just a single build.
I set "Trigger a build on each check-in" to true, but nevertheless there should only be a single build because there is only one new commit.
It seems that TeamCity triggers a build for each commit within the current month.
All builds of branch `A` finished and the same build configuration is used to build branch `A` and `B`.
Can I configure TeamCity to create builds just for the commits that haven't been built (no matter on which branch)?

Comment: I've had this happen before, but I'm not sure what the reason was. In this case I cancel all the outstanding builds and then rerun the build, which always seems to batch the changes altogether in one build.

Comment: Of course this would work, but it's obviously not a sustainable solution. Can you remember if you changed anything or did it just disappear or did you reinstall the whole system?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you faced with this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-29820).
As current workaround please try to set

```
teamcity.vcsTrigger.runBuildOnSameRevisionInEveryBranch=false
```

You can set it either as a parameter in build configuration - to affect a particular build configuration, or in [internal.properties file](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+TeamCity+Server+Startup+Properties#ConfiguringTeamCityServerStartupProperties-TeamCityinternalpropertiesinternal.properties) to affect all build configurations.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the job, although it still triggers a build when a new branch without changes is created. But I guess one build won't hurt.

Comment: Where to set this? Exactly? Why can't there be some kind of interface with checkboxes for those boolean values.

Comment: You can set it either as a parameter in build configuration - to affect a particular build configuration, or in [internal.properties](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+TeamCity+Server+Startup+Properties#ConfiguringTeamCityServerStartupProperties-TeamCityinternalproperties) to affect all build configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have activated the VCS build trigger for that Build Configuration. So, go to that Build Configuration settings page > Triggers > and look for the VCS trigger. Click the edit link and a modal will appear, there will be the option you are looking for: "Trigger a build on each check in": https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-PercheckinTriggering

Comment: Thanks. Although I want it to trigger on each check-in. But imagine I work on a feature branch which gets continuously built by TeamCity. When I then merge it back to the main branch I don't want a build triggered for each commit as they already have been triggered on the other branch.

Comment: So `runBuildOnSameRevisionInEveryBranch` seems exactly what i wanted.